What's the best way to let a Hugging Face Space pull a private Python library?
Say you have a Hugging Face Space that depends on a Python library that you host on GitHub in a private repository. Normally, you'd simply add git+https://github.com/umarbutler/mylibrary.git to your requirements.txt and then Hugging Face would automatically install the library on startup.
If the repository is private, however, you need to authenticate to be able to pull the repository. So then you could do git+https://${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/umarbutler/mylibrary.git and then add GIT_TOKEN as a secret in your space, GIT_TOKEN being a personal access token. The problem is when you are trying to do this for an organisation and there is no guarantee that the employee who used their personal access token will always be there. What do you do in that case?

I am not understanding.... So, you are working for an organization.... Yet the repo you are trying to pull from is private and not owned by the organization?

It is a private repo hosted by the organisation.
